# H2 database create alias for function in package in schema

Tags: kotlin, h2

In my code I call stored procedure like this (and it works perfectly):

`{ ? = call schema.package.function(?) }`

I need to call it like this because jdbc connection is set to another schema.

But for now I can't test it because H2 database doesn't support packages. So if I change my jdbc url database name to the one I require and delete "`schema`" from the call everything is ok while testing.

```
@Test
fun test() {
        val session = em.entityManager.unwrap(Session::class.java)

        session.doWork {
            val st = it.createStatement()
            st.execute("create schema if not exists mySchema")
            st.execute("create alias mySchema.myPackage.myFunction for " // the error happens here  +
                    "\"${this.javaClass.name}.myFunction\"")
        }

        val response = dao.myFunction("1")

        //test stuff


    }
```

How can I change my test because now it's giving me the syntax error?

Comment: Can you add the error output?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal no, sorry

Comment: i am also still finding.